# Grouping extreme value bins into one "> x" bin

Tags: r, histogram

Does a function / method already exist to determine the frequency of data greater than some value?  Similar to the Excel frequency distribution, I would like to group extreme values into the last bin (e.g., >120 as in image).  I have been doing this manually by first using the hist function and then summing the counts for breaks greater than a given value.

[image: Histogram with bins, 0, 10, 20, ..., 120, >120]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
d <- rlnorm(1000, 3)
d.cut <- cut(d, c(seq(0, 120, 10), Inf))
hist(as.numeric(d.cut), breaks=0:13, xaxt='n', xlab='', 
     col=1, border=0, main='', cex.axis=0.8, las=1)
axis(1, at=0:13, labels=c(seq(0, 120, 10), '>120'), cex.axis=0.8)
box()
```

[image]