# ggplot2 histogram with outlier bin from tibble?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, tibble, outliers

Much like [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152123/creating-greater-than-bins-in-ggplot2-histogram), I am trying to create some histograms with ggplot2 and would like to add a "greater than X"-bin that includes all values greater than some value.

In this particular case, I am dealing with a set of bike trip data with trip durations that vary from very small (under a minute) to very, very large (hours to days).  I have `filter()`ed the set to remove the truly extraneous rows, but I would still like to show some of the outliers on the plot.

I had already found the solution given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152123), the package [ggoutlier](https://github.com/EdwinTh/ggoutlier/), but it evidently requires the data be in a `data.frame`—I get an error message that `"is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE"`.  This is correct, `x` is a tibble—is there another solution that works with a tibble?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data and code you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would doubt that your issue is related to your dataset being a `tibble` as a tibble is still a dataframe and hence `is.data.frame` should give TRUE, check e.g. `is.data.frame(tibble(mtcars))`. Hence I would suggest to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data and the code you have tried.